# Why phantomjs not working in MacOS Sierra?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, osx-elcapitan, macos-sierra

We are using **phantomjs-1.9.1-macosx**, **phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx** which one working fine on **OS X El Capitan** after having update with **MacOS Sierra** it raise following errors:

**phantomjs-1.9.1-macosx**

```
$ ./phantomjs-1.9.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs -v
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx**

```
./phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs -v
Killed: 9
```

Anybody face such type of difficulties and overcome it? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and install phantomjs again?

Comment: **phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx**  working on **MacOS Sierra** but *qunit* test cases hang out the system

Comment: That happened to me too, any updates regarding that?

Comment: **phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx** with **jasmine-maven-plugin** is the solution, unable work with qunit