# Why ruby gem, brew and sencha cmd not working in MacOS Sierra?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, homebrew, sencha-cmd, macos-sierra

I was highly ambitious about **MacOS Sierra** release **version 10.12** but it's verily dishearten me causes of broken development environment. Crashes most of my project those were smoothly developed and deployment on previous version of **OS X El Capitan**. Ruby gem show following messages:

```
$ gem -v
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin16/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
2.5.0
```

**sencha cmd** unable to build project for error from Ruby

```
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin16/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
```

Also build failure for error from **phantomjs**

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 139
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMetho
[ERR] dAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

[phantomjs failure/crashed in MacOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721538), brew not working properly as it's depend on Ruby. Following error occurred with message:

```
brew update
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin16/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Already up-to-date.
```

In this situation it's a disaster for me. I wanna get relief from this situation. After googling an hours or more found the common opinion from the expertise that it's quite impossible to revert it to **OS X El Capitan**. But there is an option of install of **OS X El Capitan**. Do you have any suggestion regarding to issue?

Comment: have you installed `xcode`? try to run `xcode-select --install`, it will take some time

Comment: Thanks a lots, it's fixed all the error related to `xcode command line utility`. But there are still errors with **phantomjs-1.9.1-macosx, phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx**. Only  working with **phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx** where `Sencha Cmd v5.0.3.324` depends on earlier version of `phantomjs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of OSX/macOS have implemented a system called [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204899) which restricts user access to writing to certain directories such as `/usr`, `/var`, `/sys` etc. Most of these permissions can be changed fairly simply (`/usr/bin` is one I've had to change after a few OS upgrades) however the top-level directories I mentioned before are impossible to change permissions for without booting into recovery mode, even with `sudo` or `root`.

From the error messages it appears Ruby is having trouble writing to `/usr/local/bin`, which is also used by Homebrew to store binaries, and is also encouraged by Apple to be used for storing user-made executables and binaries. To change the permissions for `/usr/local/bin` and any other directories causing trouble, try executing:

`sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/bin`

And then re-running any commands using Ruby that failed.
Hope this helps!

Comment: after installing `xcode command line utility` then you have to execute `sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Did that fix it completely?

Comment: That's fixed error belongs to `Ruby`, `gem`, `brew`. Then we have to update `Sencha Cmd` to the version `v6.2.0.103` as well as `phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx`.